# Can not use FAB in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I got error named parmater `floatingActionButton` is not defined.

This my code of `main.dart`:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('appname'),
      ),
      body: PageView(
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        onPageChanged: (index) {
          indexcontroller.add(index);
        },
        controller: pageController,
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: GoogleMap(
              mapType: MapType.hybrid,
              initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
              onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                _controller.complete(controller);
              },
              myLocationEnabled: true,
            ),
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
              onPressed: _currentLocation,
              label: Text('My Home!'),
              icon: Icon(Icons.location_on),
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: Text('tab2'),
          ),
          Center(
            child: Text('tab3'),
          ),
          Center(
            child: Text('tab4'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Problem

You are trying to add `FloatingActionButton` as parameter of `PageView`. But direct parent of the FAB should be `Scaffold`.

## Solution

You should add your FAB as `floatingActionButton` in `Scaffold`:

```
return MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      
    ),

    body: PageView(
      
    ),
    
    // HERE ADD FAB
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
      onPressed: _currentLocation,
      label: Text('My Home!'),
      icon: Icon(Icons.location_on),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your `FloatingActionButton` outside of the `body` in the `Scaffold`. Right now it's directly inside the `body`.